# ScalaSpark - Create a pair RDD with a key and a list of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a log file with a data as the following:

```
1,2008-10-23 16:05:05.0,\N,Donald,Becton,2275 Washburn Street,Oakland,CA,94660,5100032418,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0
2,2008-11-12 03:00:01.0,\N,Donna,Jones,3885 Elliott Street,San Francisco,CA,94171,4150835799,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0
```

I need to create a pair RDD with the postal code as the key and a list of names `(Last Name,First Name)` in that postal code as the value.

I need to use `mapValues` and I did the following:

```
val namesByPCode = accountsdata.keyBy(line => line.split(',')(8)).mapValues(fields => (fields(0), (fields(4), fields(5)))).collect()
```

but I'm getting an error. can someone tell me what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keyBy` doesn't change the value, so the value stays a single "unsplit" string. You want to first use `map` to perform the split (to get an `RDD[Array[String]]`), and then use `keyBy` and `mapValues` as you did on the split result:

```
val namesByPCode = accountsdata.map(_.split(","))
  .keyBy(_(8))
  .mapValues(fields => (fields(0), (fields(4), fields(5))))
  .collect()
```

BTW - per your description, sounds like you'd also want to call `groupByKey` on this result (before calling `collect`), if you want each zipcode to evaluate into a single record with a list of names. `keyBy` doesn't perform the grouping, it just turns an `RDD[V]` into an `RDD[(K, V)]` leaving each record a single record (with  potentially many records with same "key").

Comment: Hello Tzach, This didn't work actually, I used val namesByPCode = accountsByPCode.mapValues(fields => (fields(3), fields(4))).collect() because namesByPCode  is already keyed by postal code, but when I try to print it using mkSting(), I get error: value mkString is not a member of (String, String), can you advise?

Comment: where did `accountsByPCode` come from? it doesn't exist in the question. If `accountsdata` is the plain text RDD, this does what the question asks for - try it, and if it works, please accept the answer for future readers to see. Don't ask a new question in the comments...

Comment: Plus see my comment in the answer about adding a `groupByKey` call, maybe that's what you're missing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it did work. Now I'm trying to print the first 5 zip codes and list the names as follows:                                                        println(s"======= namesByPCode, style2 =======")
 for (pair <- namesByPCode.sortByKey().take(5)) {
    println("---" + pair._1)
    pair._2.take(3)foreach(println)
 } --> but I got this error: <console>:37: error: value sortByKey is not a member of Array[(String, (String,(String, String)))]